# Why won't my ceiling light turn off?

Tags: electrical, lighting

My ceiling light won't turn off.  There are 2 separate switches to choose from to use.  Neither will turn the light off. One makes the light flicker a bit, but not off the other doesn't seem to be working at all.
This is a recent problem, has worked since room built 8 years ago.

Comment: Did both switches work the light before this? If not, it sounds like a failed switch. If this WAS a three-way circuit, I can't think of a way for that to happen other than a short circuit -- have you modified any wiring recently?

Comment: Or the travellers short circuited (maybe by a nail going through them)

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem. Did you ever find a solution, and if so, could you share it please?

Answer (score 2):

If you've modified any wiring recently, you may have accidentally connected two separate circuits.  Otherwise, the only thing I can think of that could cause this is a short-circuit.

Either case is *(very)* potentially dangerous.  If you don't feel comfortable tracking down electrical issues yourself, I would call a licensed electrician right away.